# Delete using inner join between tables in separate servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am connecting 2 servers using sp_addlinkedserver.
Then I need to delete using inner join. My sql is

```
DELETE [server1].[database1].[dbo].orders 
FROM [server1].[database1].[dbo].orders
INNER JOIN [server2].[database2].[dbo].DeletedKeys
    ON [server1].[database1].[dbo].orders.ID = 
           [server2].[database2].[dbo].DeletedKeys.Id
```

But it is giving an error:

> The multi-part identifier "[server1].[database1].[dbo].orders.ID" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "[server2].[database2].[dbo].DeletedKeys.Id" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1):

What if you alias the 4-part name?

```
DELETE o
FROM 
    [server1].[database1].[dbo].orders o
    INNER JOIN [server2].[database2].[dbo].DeletedKeys dk
        ON o.ID = dk.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully `connected and logged in` to both servers, following query will do the job.

```
DELETE [server1].[database1].[dbo].orders 
WHERE  ID IN 
     (SELECT dk.Id FROM [server2].[database2].[dbo].DeletedKeys dk)
```